# text-wrap property in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I have a very long text, in the categories. I want from a point text occupies the next line. How can I do it?

[image]

```
labels: {     
              x: -5,
              y: -20,
              useHTML: true,
              format: '<div style="position: absolute; left: 40px"> my labelL is very large ***************************************this in other line! </div> <img style="height: 30px; width: 30px; margin-top: 10px"  src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-3d-printer-icon-set/512/Plastic_model.png"></img>'       
        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fa04pp0f/

Comment: you could use `word-wrap: break-word;` in css. Then add a fixed width for your dic

Comment: @JohnPangilinan you can help? I tried but did not work for me.

Comment: In your div, you should define width and set white-space:normal; http://jsfiddle.net/u1q3pjt0/